# Airflow - Broken DAG - Timeout

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that executes a function that connects to a Postgres DB, deletes the contents in the table and then inserts a new data set.

I am trying this in my local and I see when I try to run this, the web server takes a long time to connect and in most cases doesn't succeed. However as part of the connecting process it seems to be executing the queries from the back-end. Since I have a delete function I see the data getting deleted from the table(basically one of the functions gets executed) even though I have not scheduled the script or manually started. Could someone advice as to what I am doing wrong in this.

One error that pops out in the UI is

**Broken DAG: [/Users/user/airflow/dags/dwh_sample23.py] Timeout**

Also see an i next to the dag id in the UI that says T**his is DAG isn't available in the web server's DAG object.**
Given below is the code I am using:

```
## Third party Library Imports
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'admin',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 21),
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('dwh_sample23', default_args=default_args)


#######################
## Login to DB

def db_login():
    ''' This function connects to the Data Warehouse and returns the cursor to execute queries '''
global dwh_connection
try:
    dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(" dbname = 'dbname' user = 'user' password = 'password' host = 'hostname' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
print('Success')
return(dwh_connection)

def tbl1_del():
''' This function takes clears all rows from tbl1 '''
cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
cur.execute("""DELETE FROM tbl1;""")
dwh_connection.commit()


def pop_tbl1():
''' This function populates all rows in tbl1 '''
cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO tbl1
select id,name,price from tbl2;""")
dwh_connection.commit()



db_login()
tbl1_del()
pop_tbl1()
dwh_connection.close()

##########################################


t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='DB_Connect',
python_callable=db_login(),
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/dwh_sample23.py',
dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
task_id='del',
python_callable=tbl1_del(),
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/dwh_sample23.py',
dag=dag)


t3 = BashOperator(
task_id='populate',
python_callable=pop_tbl1(),
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/dwh_sample23.py',
dag=dag)


t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
```

Could anyone assist? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `BashOperator` you can use `PythonOperator` and call `db_login()`, `tbl1_del()`, `pop_tbl1()` in `PythonOperator`

```py
## Third party Library Imports
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'admin',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 5, 21),
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}

dag = DAG('dwh_sample23', default_args=default_args)


#######################
## Login to DB

def db_login():
    ''' This function connects to the Data Warehouse and returns the cursor to execute queries '''
global dwh_connection
try:
    dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(" dbname = 'dbname' user = 'user' password = 'password' host = 'hostname' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
print('Success')
return(dwh_connection)

def tbl1_del():
''' This function takes clears all rows from tbl1 '''
cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
cur.execute("""DELETE FROM tbl1;""")
dwh_connection.commit()


def pop_tbl1():
''' This function populates all rows in tbl1 '''
cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO tbl1
select id,name,price from tbl2;""")
dwh_connection.commit()



db_login()
tbl1_del()
pop_tbl1()
dwh_connection.close()

##########################################


t1 = PythonOperator(
task_id='DB_Connect',
python_callable=db_login(),
dag=dag)

t2 = PythonOperator(
task_id='del',
python_callable=tbl1_del(),
dag=dag)


t3 = PythonOperator(
task_id='populate',
python_callable=pop_tbl1(),
dag=dag)


t1.set_downstream(t2)
t2.set_downstream(t3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. One quick question is since I am running this locally and using a SQLite DB do you think that will impact executing these DAGs.

Comment: get the below error after changing to "PythonOperator"

DeprecationWarning: Importing PythonOperator directly from <module 'airflow.operators' from '/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/__init__.py'> has been deprecated. Please import from '<module 'airflow.operators' from '/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/__init__.py'>.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0. DeprecationWarning)

Could you please assist on this..

Comment: instead of this `from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
` use this import `from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator`

Comment: thanks. I now face the below error

ERROR [root] Process timed out
ERROR [airflow.models.DagBag] Failed to import: /Users/user/airflow/dags/dwh_sample23.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 263, in process_file
    
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/timeout.py", line 38, in handle_timeout
    raise AirflowTaskTimeout(self.error_message)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: Timeout
Done.

Could you please assist on this. Thnx..

Answer (score 1):

This is really old by now, but we got this error in prod and I found this question, and think its nice that it would have an answer.

Some of the code is getting executed during DAG load, i.e. you actually run

```py
db_login()
tbl1_del()
pop_tbl1()
dwh_connection.close()
##########################################
```

inside webserver and scheduler loop, when they load dag definition from the file.
I believe you didn't intend that to happen.
Everything should work just fine if you just remove these 4 lines.

Generally don't place function you want executors to execute on file/module level, because when interpreter of the scheduler/webserver loads the file to get dag definition, it would invoke them.

Just try putting this in your dag file and see check webserver logs to see what happens.

```py
from time import sleep
def do_some_printing():
    print(1111111)
    sleep(60)

do_some_printing()
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue but the file that is throwing the error is my main dynamic DAG generator with python codes outside dag. what should i do in this case?